# How to implement hierarchical model in Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, model, sencha-touch

I have read many questions/answers and tutorials and I still fail to implement hierarchical model in Sencha Touch. The root model is Tag. Each Tag has many Items. Here is my model:

The root tag:

```
app.models.Tag = Ext.regModel("Tag", {
    fields : [ {
        name : "id",
        type : "int"
    }, {
        name : "name",
        type : "string"
    }], 
    associations : {
        type : "hasMany",
        model : "TagItem", 
        name : "items"
    }
});
```

Adjected TagItem

```
app.models.TagItem = Ext.regModel("TagItem", {
    fields : [ {
        name : "id",
        type : "int"
    }, {
        name : "title",
        type : "string"
    }, {
        name : "type", 
        type : "string"
    }, {
        name : "tag_id", 
        type : "int"
    }], 
    associations : {
        belongsTo : {
            model : "Tag",
            name : "items"
        }
    }
});
```

TagStore:

```
app.stores.tagItems = new Ext.data.Store({
    model : "app.models.TagItem",
    proxy : {
        type : 'scripttag',
        root : 'items',
        url : 'http://www.s-lab.cz/ios/api/tags.php'
    }
});
```

Tags:

```
app.stores.tags = new Ext.data.Store({
    model : "app.models.TagItems",
    proxy : {
        type : 'scripttag',
        url : 'http://www.s-lab.cz/ios/api/tags.php'
    }
});
```

When I try to load items from the store I get:

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'read' of undefined*

My JSON looks like this:

```
stcCallback1005([
 {
    "id":1,
    "name":"Doktor",
    "url":"doktor",
    "items":[
       {
          "type":"video",
          "id":1,
          "title":"First tag item",
          "tag_id":1
       },
       {
          "type":"article",
          "id":1,
          "title":"Second tag item - article",
          "tag_id":1
       },
       {
          "type":"article",
          "id":2,
          "title":"Third tag item - article",
          "tag_id":1
       },
       {
          "type":"video",
          "id":2,
          "title":"Fourth tag item",
          "tag_id":1
       }
    ]
 },
 {
    "id":2,
    "name":"Nemocnice",
    "url":"nemocnice"
 },
 {
    "id":3,
    "name":"Sestra",
    "url":"sestra"
     }
  ]);
```

**Update:**

I changed the code with suggestions and the resulting JSON is like this:

```
stcCallback1005({
    "results": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Doktor",
        "url": "doktor",
        "items": [{
            "type": "video",
            "id": 1,
            "title": "First tag item",
            "tag_id": 1
        }, {
            "type": "article",
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Second tag item - article",
            "tag_id": 1
        }, {
            "type": "article",
            "id": 2,
            "title": "Third tag item - article",
            "tag_id": 1
        }, {
            "type": "video",
            "id": 2,
            "title": "Fourth tag item",
            "tag_id": 1
        }]
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Nemocnice",
        "url": "nemocnice"
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Sestra",
        "url": "sestra"
    }]
});
```

But still I'm not able to access the subsequent items: `app.stores.tags.getAt(0)` works, but `app.stores.tags.getAt(0).TagItems()` does not (neither `app.stores.tags.getAt(0).items` or `app.stores.tags.getAt(0).items()` does). And also my template doesn't render correctly: `<tpl for=".">{name}<ul><tpl for="items"><li>{title} ({type})</li></tpl></ul></tpl>`

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think you don't need to assign a variable for model registration.**

```
Ext.regModel("Tag", {
    fields : [ {
        name : "id",
        type : "int"
    }, {
        name : "name",
        type : "string"
    }], 
    associations : {
        type : "hasMany",
        model : "TagItem", 
        name : "items"
    }
});
```

So;

```
Ext.regModel("TagItem", {
    fields : [ {
        name : "id",
        type : "int"
    }, {
        name : "title",
        type : "string"
    }, {
        name : "type", 
        type : "string"
    }, {
        name : "tag_id", 
        type : "int"
    }], 
    associations : {
        belongsTo : {
            model : "Tag",
            name : "items"
        }
    }
});
```

**Add reader to json and correct registered model names.**

TagStore:

```
app.stores.tagItems = new Ext.data.Store({
    model : "TagItem", //Use registered name
    proxy : {
        type : 'scripttag',
        url : 'http://www.s-lab.cz/ios/api/tags.php'

                   reader: { //add reader to read from json
                      type: 'json',
                      root: 'results'
                   }
    }
});
```

Tags:

```
app.stores.tags = new Ext.data.Store({
    model : "Tag", //Use registered name
    proxy : {
        type : 'scripttag',
        url : 'http://www.s-lab.cz/ios/api/tags.php'
                   reader: { //add reader to read from json
                      type: 'json',
                     root: 'results'
                   }
    }
});
```

**And finally maybe you need to change your json format in tags.php as;**

```
{"results":[
 {
    "id":1,
    "name":"Doktor",
    "url":"doktor",
    "items":[
       {
          "type":"video",
          "id":1,
          "title":"First tag item",
          "tag_id":1
       },
       {
          "type":"article",
          "id":1,
          "title":"Second tag item - article",
          "tag_id":1
       },
       {
          "type":"article",
          "id":2,
          "title":"Third tag item - article",
          "tag_id":1
       },
       {
          "type":"video",
          "id":2,
          "title":"Fourth tag item",
          "tag_id":1
       }
    ]
 },
 {
    "id":2,
    "name":"Nemocnice",
    "url":"nemocnice"
 },
 {
    "id":3,
    "name":"Sestra",
    "url":"sestra"
     }
  ]
}
```

**I hope it works or helps to correct your code.**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it didn't help. See updated question.